Problem with displaying labels when adding to different panels in Java Swing
My software product has two tabs: "Create Object" and "Output All Objects". When I add a label label1 to both the Create Object tab and the Output All Objects tab, it disappears from the first tab and appears only in the second. If you add label1 to the second tab and then to the first, label1 will appear only on the first tab
Example problem
The part of the code where the problem is:
        PanelInputCamera.add(label1);
        PanelInputCamera.add(jTextField1);
        PanelInputCamera.add(label2);
        PanelInputCamera.add(jTextField2);
        PanelInputCamera.add(label3);
        PanelInputCamera.add(jTextField3);
        PanelInputCamera.add(label4);
        PanelInputCamera.add(jTextField4);
        PanelInputCamera.add(label5);
        PanelInputCamera.add(jTextField5);
        PanelInputCamera.add(label6);
        PanelInputCamera.add(jTextField6);
        PanelInputCamera.add(label7);
        PanelInputCamera.add(jTextField7);

        PanelOutputCamera.add(label1);
        PanelOutputCamera.add(jTextField1);
        PanelOutputCamera.add(label2);
        PanelOutputCamera.add(jTextField2);
        PanelOutputCamera.add(label3);
        PanelOutputCamera.add(jTextField3);
        PanelOutputCamera.add(label4);
        PanelOutputCamera.add(jTextField4);
        PanelOutputCamera.add(label5);
        PanelOutputCamera.add(jTextField5);
        PanelOutputCamera.add(label6);
        PanelOutputCamera.add(jTextField6);
        PanelOutputCamera.add(label7);
        PanelOutputCamera.add(jTextField7);

Full code:
package com.example.main;


import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

// Використання об'єктів як посилального типу
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JFrame window = new JFrame();
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        window.setSize(800, 600);

        JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();
        tabbedPane.setFocusable(false);
        window.add(tabbedPane);

        JPanel PanelInputCamera = new JPanel();
        JPanel PanelOutputCamera = new JPanel();

        PanelInputCamera.setLayout(new GridLayout(20, 1));

        JLabel label1 = new JLabel("Model Type");
        JLabel label2 = new JLabel("Manufacturer");
        JLabel label3 = new JLabel("Memory Type");
        JLabel label4 = new JLabel("Price");
        JLabel label5 = new JLabel("Size");
        JLabel label6 = new JLabel("Lens Type");
        JLabel label7 = new JLabel("Focal Distance");

        JTextField jTextField1 = new JTextField(10);
        JTextField jTextField2 = new JTextField(10);
        JTextField jTextField3 = new JTextField(10);
        JTextField jTextField4 = new JTextField(10);
        JTextField jTextField5 = new JTextField(10);
        JTextField jTextField6 = new JTextField(10);
        JTextField jTextField7 = new JTextField(10);

        PanelInputCamera.add(label1);
        PanelInputCamera.add(jTextField1);
        PanelInputCamera.add(label2);
        PanelInputCamera.add(jTextField2);
        PanelInputCamera.add(label3);
        PanelInputCamera.add(jTextField3);
        PanelInputCamera.add(label4);
        PanelInputCamera.add(jTextField4);
        PanelInputCamera.add(label5);
        PanelInputCamera.add(jTextField5);
        PanelInputCamera.add(label6);
        PanelInputCamera.add(jTextField6);
        PanelInputCamera.add(label7);
        PanelInputCamera.add(jTextField7);

        PanelOutputCamera.add(label1);
        PanelOutputCamera.add(jTextField1);
        PanelOutputCamera.add(label2);
        PanelOutputCamera.add(jTextField2);
        PanelOutputCamera.add(label3);
        PanelOutputCamera.add(jTextField3);
        PanelOutputCamera.add(label4);
        PanelOutputCamera.add(jTextField4);
        PanelOutputCamera.add(label5);
        PanelOutputCamera.add(jTextField5);
        PanelOutputCamera.add(label6);
        PanelOutputCamera.add(jTextField6);
        PanelOutputCamera.add(label7);
        PanelOutputCamera.add(jTextField7);

        tabbedPane.add("Create Object", PanelInputCamera);
        tabbedPane.add("Output all objects", PanelOutputCamera);

        window.setVisible(true);
    }
}

I have tried adding the label to 2 different Panels but the label is only displayed in one of them, I expected the label to be displayed in each of the panels

@PM77-1 Yes, that answers my question. I googled before asking the question, I think I'm going to delete my question now, thanks so much for your help!
